# XSLT: How to get the distinct value from between two xml

Tags: xml, xslt

My aim i just to want to get the distinct the value, i mean, no of 10th `td` value that is available in the second xml( xml file through 'document' function) and it should not be available in the source xml, this value i am treating as 'dintinct' value. How I can get this? I tried above code and it does not provide exact distinct values that i expect. Any help?

[XSLT: How to compare two xml files and how to get distinct value from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628901/xslt-how-to-compare-two-xml-files-and-how-to-get-distinct-value-from-it) based on this question, I tried the following with input xml files, but, even, i am not able to get the distinct text between two files.

For example, as per the correct result, here, this `<distint>Meat and edible meat offal.</distint>` not supposed to come. But, right now, it is coming and this is wrong.

XSL file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:variable name="check" select="normalize-space(substring(//document[@indent='-2']/documenttitle,3))"/>

<xsl:template match="/">    
<xsl:for-each select="document('Main2.xml')//*[local-name()='tr']/*[local-name()='td'][10][./preceding-sibling::td[5][. != '']]">
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test=". = $check">
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
 <xsl:text>

 </xsl:text>
 <distint><xsl:value-of select="."/></distint>
 </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>  

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Source XML

```
<XML>
    <documents>
    <document indent="-3">
      <document_prefixtitle>Some text</document_prefixtitle>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>1 Live animals.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>2 Meat and edible meat offal.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>3 Fish and crustaceans, molluscs and other aquatic invertebrates.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>4 Dairy produce; birds eggs; natural honey; edible products of animal origin, not elsewhere specified or included.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>5 Products of animal origin, not elsewhere specified or included.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>6 Live trees and other plants; bulbs, roots and the like; cut flowers and ornamental foliage.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>7 Edible vegetables and certain roots and tubers.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>8 Edible fruit and nuts; peel of citrus fruit or melons.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>9 Coffee, tea mat, and spices.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>10 Cereals.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>11 Products of the milling industry; malt; starches; inulin; wheat gluten.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>12 Oil seeds and oleaginous fruits; miscellaneous grains, seeds and fruit; industrial or medicinal plants; straw and fodder.</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>13 Example of distint chaptrr fruits; miscellaneous grains</documenttitle></document>
<document indent="-2"><documenttitle>14 1Example of distint chaptrr fruits; miscellaneous grains</documenttitle></document>
</document></documents></XML>
```

XML that is taken through 'document' function is:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Live animals.</td></tr>

<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Meat and edible meat offal.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Fish and crustaceans, molluscs and other aquatic invertebrates.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Dairy produce; birds eggs; natural honey; edible products of animal origin, not elsewhere specified or included.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Products of animal origin, not elsewhere specified or included.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Live trees and other plants; bulbs, roots and the like; cut flowers and ornamental foliage.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Edible vegetables and certain roots and tubers.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Edible fruit and nuts; peel of citrus fruit or melons.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Coffee, tea mat, and spices.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Cereals.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Products of the milling industry; malt; starches; inulin; wheat gluten.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Oil seeds and oleaginous fruits; miscellaneous grains, seeds and fruit; industrial or medicinal plants; straw and fodder.</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Live animals new sample.</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>_24</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td>20141210</td>
<td></td><td>Active Live animals new sample.</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

As of now, am getting the result as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<distint>Meat and edible meat offal.</distint>
<distint>Fish and crustaceans, molluscs and other aquatic invertebrates.</distint>
<distint>Dairy produce; birds eggs; natural honey; edible products of animal origin, not elsewhere specified or included.</distint>
<distint>Products of animal origin, not elsewhere specified or included.</distint>
<distint>Live trees and other plants; bulbs, roots and the like; cut flowers and ornamental foliage.</distint>
<distint>Edible vegetables and certain roots and tubers.</distint>
<distint>Edible fruit and nuts; peel of citrus fruit or melons.</distint>
<distint>Coffee, tea mat, and spices.</distint>
<distint>Cereals.</distint>
<distint>Products of the milling industry; malt; starches; inulin; wheat gluten.</distint>
<distint>Oil seeds and oleaginous fruits; miscellaneous grains, seeds and fruit; industrial or medicinal plants; straw and fodder.</distint>
<distint>Live animals new sample.</distint>
<distint>Active Live animals new sample.</distint>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reson why this doesn't work is that you're comparing everything to `$check` - but the `$check` variable contains only this:

```
"Live animals."
```

This is because the substring()function (like all string functions) operates only on the first node in the node-set specified by the first argument.

If you want to strip the numbering from the `<documenttitle>` nodes, you must do so for each and every one of them. And you cannot use `substring(., 3)` because your numbers go above 9.

Comment: Could you please correct my code above or else give some coding sample on this.

Comment: Actually, I am not getting your last line of your explanation on substring, Could you please eloborate?

Comment: @Sakthivel `substring('10 Cereals.', 3)` returns `"  Cereals."` (with a leading space). Eliminating the leading space by using normalize-space() on the result  will make you safe up to 99. `substring('100 Cereals.', 3)` returns `"0 Cereals."` A better method would be to use `substring-after(., ' ')`.